# How to find the angle between three points with openlayers?

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I use openlayers version 6.5.

I want to find the angle between two lines or three points.

Is there a library to reference or how to get it?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jFaP3.png)

No related library was found.
Should I solve it mathematically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [dot product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product):

The dot product of two normalized vectors is equal to angle between them.
In general case when the vectors are not normalized the equation is the following:

```
cos(a^b) = dot(a,b) / length(a) / length(b)
```

Thus:

```
a^b = arccos(dot(a,b) / length(a) / length(b))
```

Or:

```
a^b = arccos( (a.x*b.x + a.y*b.y + a.z*b.z) / sqrt(a.x^2+a.y^2+a.z^2) / sqrt(b.x^2+b.y^2+b.z^2) )
```